# How to Determine Blender's Status When Logs Freeze During Rendering?

Tags: rendering

Blender hangs, how can I get the status of Blender to know whether it has frozen or not? I have a server on Ubuntu that launches Blender via a Python script, and I receive logs about the execution of its render, but at some point, the logs freeze and that's it, the process hangs. I can track the status through logs, but it's not the best solution, so I'd like to get the status from Blender itself. If I don't receive anything, I'll also understand that Blender has hung.